# I am adding a scroll programatically, but for some reason it doesn't start at the start

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview

I am adding a scroll programatically, but for some reason it doesn't start at the start.

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.frame];
self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self addSubview:self.scrollView];
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Here are some logs:

```
NSLog(@"contentOffset - %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(self.scrollView.contentOffset));
NSLog(@"contentSize - %@",NSStringFromCGSize(self.scrollView.contentSize));
NSLog(@"contentInset - %@",NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets(self.scrollView.contentInset));
NSLog(@"frame - %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.scrollView.frame));

2014-03-20 12:53:56.356 contentOffset - {0, 0}
2014-03-20 12:53:56.357 contentSize - {320, 423}
2014-03-20 12:53:56.357 contentInset - {0, 0, 0, 0}
2014-03-20 12:53:56.358 frame - {{0, 156}, {320, 423}}
2014-03-20 12:53:56.360 contentOffset - {0, 0}
2014-03-20 12:53:56.360 contentSize - {320, 423}
2014-03-20 12:53:56.361 contentInset - {0, 0, 0, 0}
2014-03-20 12:53:56.361 frame - {{0, 156}, {320, 423}}
```

[image]

Comment: What is NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame)) ?

Comment: Instead of self.frame try self.bounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `self.frame` try `self.bounds`.

Frame is position with respect to the superview. But bounds start from (0,0)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this:

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.frame];
```

should be:

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds];
```

Notice how your print out has this:  `frame - {{0, 156}, {320, 423}}`

This means your scrollview is not starting at the top, its starting at `156px`

`self.bounds` will always contain `{{0, 0}, {<view-width>, <view-height>}}`

Answer (score 0):

Might be your parent controller's  frame is not correct just check it by using

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
```

And see what is display in console ?

If it is not proper then set scrollView's frame manually like,

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, self.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer, please remove it or add something that answers the question

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin - check it now .. it is not for a comment :) THanks mate :)